# Load file into array then save back to file

Tags: c#

I'm trying to load a file and contents into an array, then add a line to a certain place in the file. For example:

[image]

So, load the file in add line into this file then copy back to array and save it up. This is the code I have so far, but I'm not sure how I would go about rebuilding it.

```
 private void addgsc()
    {
        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines
     (modspath + "//maps//_zombiemode_weapons.gsc");

        int index = -1; // Where to insert the new line.

        List<string> newLines = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            newLines.Add(lines[i]);
            if (lines[i].Contains("add_zombie_weapon"))
                index = i + 1;
        }

        if (index > -1)
        {
            newLines.Insert(index, "test 21");
        }
        string[] rebulidarr = newLines.ToArray();
```

Comment: And what's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is a series of `add_zombie_weapon()` lines, and you want to add something at the end of that section?

If so, try something like this:

```
    private void addgsc()
    {
        string file = modspath + "//maps//_zombiemode_weapons.gsc";
        List<string> lines = new List<string>(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file));
        int index = lines.FindLastIndex(item => item.Contains("add_zombie_weapon"));
        if (index != -1)
        {
            lines.Insert(index + 1, "test 21");
        }
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(file, lines);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it this way:

```
var newlines =
    from line in File.ReadAllLines("source_filename.txt")
    from newline in new []
    {
        line,
        line.Contains("add_zombie_weapon") ? "test 21 " : null
    }
    where newline != null;
    select newline;

File.WriteAllLines("destination_filename.txt", newlines);
```

Comment: This has different behavior than the OP's code in that the OP's code only inserts one `"test 21"` line--after the last line that contains `"add_zombie_weapon"`. If multiple lines contain that string, your code would add multiple `"test 21"` lines.

Comment: @JimMischel - You're right. I was, pardon the pun, reading between the lines of the OP's actual requirement.